# Text underline or border bottom custom

Tags: html, css, text

[Look at the sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POrU6.png)

Can you achieve this underlining with css? I tried to do it the following way but I can not advance to make the thin line and then make the thick line again at the end

```css
h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
}
h1:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 25%;
    height: 1px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 1%;
    border-bottom: 10px solid blue;
      h1 {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      width: 50%;
      height: 1px;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 5%;
      border-bottom: 10px solid blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>test text for show</h1>


<p>Desired final style</p>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/POrU6.png">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the border of the `h1` for the thin line and the pseudo for the thick ends

*Note, CSS does not allow one rule nested within another, as you had with the `h1` inside the `h1:before`, for that you need SCSS or SASS*

```css
h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}

h1::before,
h1::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  height: 9px;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: 0;
  background: #900;
}
h1::after {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>test text for show</h1>
```

Comment: Ready friend, I can not give you votes because I lack 15 reputation !! But check it out !! greetings and thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

check below example

```css
  .underline-text4{
      position:relative;
      padding-bottom:5px;
      display:inline-block;
      color:blue;
      border-bottom:4px solid blue
  }
.underline-text4::before{
   position: absolute;
   bottom:-7px;
   height:10px;
   width:50px;
   left:0;
   content:"";
  background:red;
}     

.underline-text4::after{
   position: absolute;
       bottom:-7px;
   height:10px;
   width:50px;
   right:0;
   content:"";
   background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="underline-text4"> This is Underlined text 3 </div>
```

More examples at

https://codepen.io/sajiddesigner/pen/QvgeGO

You can create as many different styles with different methods

Comment: That literally looks nothing like what the OP is looking for

Comment: I just gave him hints. let me update answer for him. :)

Comment: Thank you friend, vote your answer: D I like the example styles you published !! regards!!